# Where can I find the files I just installed from the software center?

Tags: search

This is a rather basic question, when I install something from the Ubuntu Software Center, I have to look around a bit to find it. For example, I just installed  but I cannot locate it. For some programs its obvious, for example Dropbox and Skype can be found in `Applications>Internet>` but for some others I am pretty clueless.

I just switched from Unity to gnome in Ubuntu 11.04, as it was a bit buggy. One thing I am beginning to miss though, is the search functionality which was quiet convenient.

Comment: The pre-11.04 version of Software Centre was showing the location of the application - something like "After installation you will find it in Applications > Internet". In the recent Ubuntu this feature has been replaced with "do you want to add the application to the launcher" thingie. The point being - "classic Gnome" is not a priority in Ubuntu currently. Hope Unity will mature in 11.10 and you'll be able to switch back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would use `synapse` as a unity replacement it will give you "similar" functionality to unity.

You will need to add there ppa to install Synapse `ppa:synapse-core/ppa`

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

As far as I know after you have installed software using the software centre it tells you which menu it would be visible, in the detailed information section where you would rate the program.
[image: Image showing section of Ubuntu Software Center]

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things you can do to find the location.

- You can look for the application in alacarte, the menu editor and optionally add/move the application to another category if you think it's necessary.
- Menuitems used by menus and alacarte, are created from .desktop-files (XML files) that you can find in /usr/share/applications/. This will state which category the application is in, what the label should be and which icon to use. It is available for all users. If you want to customize for your own needs without affecting other users, you can copy the file from /usr/share/applications/ to $HOME/.local/share/applications/.
- If you want to list all files created when installing a package, you can use dpkg -L package_name.